# Haskell. Sort by second element in the list of tuples

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, select, histogram

I have a code `histogram`, which shows the number of all characters in String.

```
histogram :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
histogram = foldr help [] where
    help x [] = [(x,1)] 
    help x ((y,z):yzs)
      | x == y = (y,z+1) : yzs 
      | otherwise = (y,z) : help x yzs
```

But the result is shown in a chaotic order. I want to sort the result by the second element of the list (i.e. by numbers). For this I implemented `ssort` code but it sorts only by the first element (char).

```
import Data.List (minimum, delete)

ssort :: Ord t => [t] -> [t]
ssort [] = []
ssort xs = x : ssort (remove x xs) where
     x = minimum xs

remove :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
remove _ [] = [] 
remove y (x:xs) | y == x = xs 
    | otherwise = x : remove y xs
```

**Input:** ssort [('a',1), ('g', 6), ('o',2), ('f',0)]

**Output:** [('a',1),('f',0),('g',6),('o',2)] (instead of [('f',0),('a',1),('o',2),('g',6)])

I also don't want to use any other builtins, as sort, sortOn and sortBy, I want to implement my own function.

How can I make it so that only the second elements are compared?

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is define your own `minimum` function then, which you can specialize to work on lists of pairs.  Something like `minimumSnd :: Ord b => [(a,b)] -> (a,b)`

Comment: @DDub You don’t even need an extra function: you can implement it as something like `minimumSnd = swap . minimum . fmap swap`, which is then easy to inline.

Comment: @bradm That's true, but the poster is not simply asking how to get the right answer, but how to _implement their own function to get there_.  Rather than simply give the answer, I was suggesting a path that @Theresa might follow that could lead to a correct implementation.  Understanding that `minimum` is the fundamental reason that `ssort` doesn't do what the poster wants is important, and fixing that implementation is the way forward.  Inlining is great once understanding is reached (indeed, the whole thing can be inlined to `sortOn snd`).

Answer (score 1):

You may provide your own definition of `minimumBy`:

```
minimumBy2 :: Ord t2 => [(t1, t2)] -> (t1, t2)
minimumBy2 (h:t) = go h t where
  go x [] = x
  go x (h0:t0) = go (min x h0) t0
minimumBy2 [] = error "minimumBy2: Empty list"
```

You can then use it in place of `minimum` in `ssort` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use `minimumBy :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> t a -> a`  as well.

You can take advantage on how are tuples compared – first by the first element and then by the second. Therefore you can first swap all of the elements of your histogram, then sort and finally swap back:

```
ssortOn2 :: (Ord t1, Ord t2) => [(t1, t2)] -> [(t1, t2)]
ssortOn2 = map swap . ssort . map swap
```

(leaving all other functions unchanged)